# I cant import dotCover report(Sonarqube)

Tags: sonarqube, report, dotcover

Sonarqube 8.1.0.31237
SonarScanner 4.1.0.1829

I cant import dotcover report(Manuel test coverage, not unit test coverage).
Code coverage=%0

I’m trying these command:

SonarScanner.MSBuild.exe begin /k:projectkey /d:sonar.cs.dotcover.reportsPaths=“coverageReport.html”

MSBuild.exe “project.sln path” /t:Rebuild

SonarScanner.MSBuild.exe end

Answer (score 0):

I believe Sonar wants the xml formatted report vs HTML.